Angular: Checkboxes becoming all checked after form submission
My form for a food item is span across 2 tabs. Both tabs contain 2 different forms built using json configs which are merged later on. The problem is after I click save and the backend validations run returning an error message if any, all the checkboxes on both tabs are checked even if I have not checked them.

you set string to your checkboxes here:
control.setValue(control.value ? 'T' : 'F');

but checkbox with form control needs a boolean, not a string. So, use only booleans throughout.
see: value attribute of a checkbox ignored using FormControl.value #30619
edit:
if you need to send string to the server, you can just replace checkbox value upon submit, for example:
onSubmit(event: Event) {

  // extract checkbox form control and convert to string, if there are more checkboxes, you'll need to get them all
  const { checkBoxProp, ...dynamicFoodMainFormModified } = this.dynamicFoodMainForm.value;
  // convert to string
  dynamicFoodMainFormModified.checkBoxProp = checkBoxProp ? 'T' : 'F';

        // pass modified data to service and then to server
    if (this.data) {
        const updatedRowData = { ...this.data, ...dynamicFoodMainFormModified };


it however works when i edit a new records. Like the field which is true has checkbox checked. But on submit, everythibg is checked. Can you provide a code snippet pls? :(

I do this to send proper value to backend for saving to database

I can't reproduce your example, as there is not enough code, but in general, just remove checkbox modifying code, just use boolean, and then, if you need to send string to the server, upon form submit, find checkbox properties, and replace them with strings, just don't use strings with checkbox form control, but boolean

BTW:

To manage a FormControl with values T/F in an input, you can use
 <input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="form.get('control.name')=='T'"
        (ngModelChange)="form.get('control.name').setValue($event?'T':'F')"
        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" 
 >


To "disable" you need use (enable/disable methods of a FormCntrol, not the attribute [disabled]



can you adapt it using my provided html? im not too sure

it's only replace your '<input formControlName="{{ control.name }}" ...>`by the new inputs. NOTE: Remember imports FormsModule in your component if is a standalone component (or in the module where your component is declared if it's not standalone.
